# Openshift details in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, environment-variables, openshift, persistent-volumes

I'm new to openshift.. Does anyone know how to configure openshift volume details in application.properties file in a spring boot application? I'm trying to access that path to upload files from my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify:

- Volumes
- VolumeMounts
- Point SpringBoot to the VolumeMounts full path.

Example in your deployment config, you would define:

In your deployment.yaml ,

```
apiVersion: apps.openshift.io/v1
kind: DeploymentConfig
.
.
.
.
.
volumes:
  - name: data
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: my-data

volumeMounts:
  - mountPath: /data/logs
    name: data
```

Then in your springboot properties you would create a property that points to the mountPath:

```
LOGS_DIR: /data/logs
```